# How to convert from Equirectangular Projection Coordinates to 3D coordinates

Tags: math, glsl, shader, trigonometry, hlsl

I use the following code to get equirectangular texture coordinates based on an object's position in the world:

```
            Equirec(positionX, positionY, positionZ) {
                radius = sqrt(positionX^2 + positionZ^2);
                a = atan2(-positionX, positionZ);
                b = atan2(positionY, radius);

                uv.x = (a - pi) / -2pi;
                uv.y = (b + pi/2) / pi;

                return uv;
            }
```

Is it possible to invert this function?

What I want to do is, given the uv coordinates returned from this function, figure out the corresponding position in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  You have thrown away information.  The UV coordinates are within a single plane.  If you knew the location of that plane in 3D space, you could do it.